# editing table row creates a clone in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to implement a edit operation in react.js. what it does now is, if i click on edit button, it shows the row data in the name and email address field. and if I submit it without any changes, it creates a clone. if I submit it with changes it creates a whole new data with new id.
Since I'm new to react, I'm trying to figure it out. Need a little help from Y'all.

here's my code

```
 import React from "react";
import { Dna } from "react-loader-spinner";
import { useState } from "react";
function Main() {
  // *****INITIALIZING*****

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [formInputData, setformInputData] = useState({
    id: Date.now(),
    Name: "",
    email: ""
  });

  // **********DECLARING FUNCTIONS*********

  const handleChange = (evnt) => {
    const newInput = (data) => ({
      ...data, id: Date.now(),
      [evnt.target.name]: evnt.target.value
    });
    setformInputData(newInput);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    setloading(true);
      const checkEmptyInput = !Object.values(formInputData).every((res) => res === "");
      if (checkEmptyInput) {
        const newData = (data) => [...data, formInputData];
        setTableData(newData);
        const emptyInput = { id: "", Name: "", email: "" };
        setformInputData(emptyInput);
      }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setloading(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleDelete = (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setloading(true);
    const newTableData = tableData.filter(data => data.id !== id);
    setTableData(newTableData)
    setEditData(null);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setloading(false)

    }, 1000)
  }

  const handleEdit = (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(id);

    const editData = tableData.find((data) => data.id == id)
    console.log(editData);
    const editIndex = tableData.indexOf(editData);
    setEditData(editIndex);
    setformInputData(editData);
  }

  // ************RETURNING VALUES************

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <div className="col">
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={formInputData.Name}
              name="Name"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Name"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <input
              type="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={formInputData.email}
              name="email"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <input
              type="submit"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              className="btn btn-success"
            /><br></br>
            {loading ? (
              <Dna
                visible={true}
                height="80"
                width="80"
                ariaLabel="dna-loading"
                wrapperStyle={{}}
                wrapperClass="dna-wrapper"
              />
            ) : (
              <div>
                {
                  <table className="table" id="table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>S.N</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {tableData.map((data, index) => {
                        return (
                          <tr>
                            <td>{data.id}</td>
                            <td>{data.Name}</td>
                            <td>{data.email}</td>
                            <td>
                              <button
                                value={data.id}
                                onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e, data.id)}
                                className="btn btn-danger"
                              >
                                Delete
                              </button> &nbsp; <button
                                value={data.id}
                                onClick={(e) => handleEdit(e, data.id)}
                                className="btn btn-danger"
                              >
                                Edit
                              </button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      })}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                }
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Main;
```

Comment: Not sure if this would fix it but have you tried giving the rows a `key` attribute, e.g. `tableData.map((data, index) => <tr key={data.id}> ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in `handleEdit()`, you shouldn't assign an ID because it creates new one every time you write a new letter in your `<input>`. Then, you should create it on `handleSubmit()`.

Every time you press submit, you are adding a new object, i.e. you are concatenating the values from data with formDataInput.

```
const newData = (data) => [...data, formInputData];
setTableData(newData);
```

You need to find the element and modify if it exists. And then update the table.

I refactored your code so now it works.

```
const handleChange = (evnt) => {
 const newInput = (data) => ({
   ...data,
   [evnt.target.name]: evnt.target.value
 });
 setformInputData(newInput);
};

const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
 evnt.preventDefault();
 setloading(true);
   const checkEmptyInput = !Object.values(formInputData).every((res) => res === "");

  if (checkEmptyInput) {

    if (tableData.filter(e => e.id === formInputData.id).length !== 0)
      setTableData([...tableData].map(e => e.id === formInputData.id ? formInputData : e));
    else {
      let newData = [...tableData]
      newData.push({id: Date.now(), Name: formInputData.Name, email: formInputData.email})
      setTableData(newData);
   }
    setformInputData({ id: "", Name: "", email: "" });
  }

 setTimeout(() => {
   setloading(false);
 }, 1000);
};

const handleDelete = (event, id) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 setloading(true);
 const newTableData = tableData.filter(data => data.id !== id);
 setTableData(newTableData)


 setTimeout(() => {
   setloading(false)

 }, 1000)
}

const handleEdit = (event, id) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const editData = tableData.find((data) => data.id === id)
  setformInputData(editData);
}
```

Finally, you will see problem as `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`. That is easy, you only have to write `<tr key={index}>`. We added index as key because its value is unique for each row i.e. each array element has a position, so if you use index, it will never be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not currently removing the original row from `data`. Filter it out in your submit handler:

```
const handleSubmit = (evnt) => {
  // ...
  if (checkEmptyInput) {
    setTableData(data => data
      .filter(row => row.id !== formInputData.id)
      .concat(formInputData));
    const emptyInput = { id: "", Name: "", email: "" };
    setformInputData(emptyInput);
  }
  // ...
};
```